# I don't wish to presume or with all due respect

Tags: phrase-usage

I was wondering if these two structure has similar meaning and use.

> I don't wish to presume

means I don't want to be rude or have right to do that

> with all due respect

is used when you are going to disagree, usually quite strongly, with somebody.

While the former stress on "not having right" and "not being rude", the latter is stress on " being disagree", the aim basically apparently the same : making suggestion.

I would like to ask which one more suitable when we make suggestions to someone who has higher rank in social ladder such as your boss or professor, especially in an email.

Comment: Using the word "respect" should be a clue. But really context will decide it.

Comment: "With all due respect" is a formula used when disagreeing with someone and usually means "I don't want to offend you, but ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never really go wrong with

> with all due respect
>
> With all due respect, I think I have a better chance than a snowball in hell.

but it it is a big red flag that you are going to disagree/contradict *something*, but is deferential to someone who is senior (either in authority or age).

> I don't wish to presume
>   I wouldn't presume
>   I wouldn't assume
>
> I wouldn't presume that a snowball always melts in hell.

is a qualifier on how one is thinking about a question

> I wouldn't *want* to assume/presume *(that)*
>
> I wouldn't want to assume that a snowball has no chance in hell, or that my chances are similar to a snowball's since either could be a black swan event.

can be used to specifically enumerate points which one disagrees with.